# React Native Facebook SDK Login: Avoid Re-Authorization in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

How do I prevent the Facebook authorization page from popping up when refreshing my React Native app?

Each time I want to test changes, I'm redirected to Safari but it says, "You have already authorized myApp." I click "OK" and I'm taken back to my app.

I'd like to avoid this unnecessary added step each time.